# Capture image from GPU

Tags: image, capture, gpu

Is there a way to capture a screenshot directly from the GPU without the need to actually display the screen on the monitor? I check lots of posts here, but only found answers for capturing screen images remotely and so forth.

Comment: The only useful answers to this question will be platform-specific, so please make your question specific enough that we can provide relevant answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in an application that you're making where you can supply code to it, you can set up a Render Target and output the result to a BMP or TGA file.